# Package ‘htmltools’ version 0.5.0 cannot be unloaded

Tags: r, package, version, importerror, htmltools

I am trying to launch a RShiny App but each time i get this message error:

> Package ‘htmltools’ version 0.5.0 cannot be unloaded:
> Error in unloadNamespace(package) : l'espace de noms ‘htmltools’ est importé par ‘shinydashboard’, ‘DT’, ‘htmlwidgets’, ‘shiny’ et ne peut, donc, pas être déchargé

Here belows the code for my libraries:

[Importation libraries code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J4YJ.png)

What I already tried:

- Reboot the session
- Desinstall htmltools and reinstall it
- charge the version 0.5.0 and not the updated one 0.5.1: If i do this, I have now the problem:

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
> le package ‘htmltools’ 0.5.0 est déjà chargé, mais >= 0.5.0.9001 est requis

- Place the library(htmltools) first, but it would still not work

By the way, I found a temporary solution which was to each time re install htmltools in packages and it would work until I end the session.

Comment: What is the output of `.libPaths()`?

Comment: it is my library for the project: "D:/IPPON/Mai 2021/PAT/PAT_v4.0.3/libs_PAT_4.0.3"